# Why are entities such as 'order' in the eav_entity_type table if they are not proper EAV entities?

Tags: magento, magento2, entity-attribute-value

The *eav_entity_type* table contains 4 'proper' EAV entities (customer, customer_address, catalog_category, catalog_product), but also some entities that are not 'proper' EAV entities, in the sense that they don't have their own [x]_entity_varchar/int/text/datetime tables and their models do not implement the *\Magento\Framework\Api\CustomAttributesDataInterface*.

Why are these entities referenced in this table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, EAV stands for Entity, Attribute, and Value. Let’s look into each part and try to understand them a little better.

Entity: The entity represents Magento data items such as products, categories, customers, and orders. Each entity (product, category, etc.) will have its own entity record in the database.

Attribute: The attributes represent data items that belong to an entity. For example, the product entity has attributes such as name, price, status, and many more.

Value: The value is the simplest to understand as it is simply a value linked to an attribute. For better understanding, let’s consider the product entity. Each product entity will have a series of attributes, one of them is the name attribute.